# Cat leg severely swollen

Tags: cats, injury

He was playing outside and I don't know what happened he meowed all of a sudden and I see this huge swell on his back leg with blood on the other leg, he also had a small wound which is much much bigger now.

[image]

[image]

This is how much it is swollen. I took him to the vet immediately and he said he isn't sure what happened and is recommending an anesthesic procedure where he can look more on the leg.

Comment: Go to the vet and allow them to treat the cat. Swelling indicates infection; the longer you delay, the higher risk to your cat's life.

Comment: as @AllisonC say your cat have an infection,what happened is not important but getting it treated is,your vet might want to take a couple of x-rays of the leg to be sure no foregn object is present in the wound.

Comment: Not sure what could’ve happened either! Maybe he got stung or bitten by something? I don’t a sting would draw blood, so maybe something larger with a little venom got him? Hopefully things are better now! Curious if the vet had any more ideas